# Cassandra cluster monitoring

Tags: cassandra, monitoring

How to collect data from all nodes within cluster from single node in cassandra.
Does jmx provide aggregated values for all nodes which are present on same cluster on single node?

Comment: Which Cassandra distribution you are using? Planet Cassandra or DataStax Cassandra or any other?

Comment: Datastax Cassandra

Comment: Okay. Can you provide more information like: 1)Which data(parameters) information you want from all nodes. 2) Are you managing the Cassandra cluster using DataStax Ops-center or not?

Comment: No I am writing my own application which will monitor performance of my entire cluster. So my doubt is can we get entire cluster level information from any single node like cluster latency.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. For Cassandra cluster you will be able to do so.As per my knowledge there are two well know ways for monitoring and getting cluster status.

1. **nodetool utility :** 
   The nodetool utility is a command-line interface for monitoring Cassandra and performing routine database operations. Included in the Cassandra distribution, nodetool and is typically run directly from an operational Cassandra node.
2. **Datastax Ops-center :** OpsCenter provides a graphical representation of performance trends in a summary view that is hard to obtain with other monitoring tools. The GUI provides views for different time periods as well as the capability to drill down on single data points. Both real-time and historical performance data for a Cassandra or DataStax Enterprise cluster are available in OpsCenter. OpsCenter metrics are captured and stored within Cassandra.

I think the the first way (nodetool utility) will be more useful to meet your requirements.

You will get more information  at 
 [Cassandra cluster monitoring](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/operations/ops_monitoring_c.html) and [nodetool options.](https://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/NodeTool)

Comment: Yes I was thinking same but there are few parameters which we don't get from nodetool directly like aggregation of read or write latency. Do you have list of such parameters which are cluster specific?

Comment: I don't have it. if you don't mine read http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/metric-collection-and-storage-with-cassandra.  It might help you get some insight.

Comment: Thank you so much. For cassandra administrator perspective what is more important cluster health or individual node health?

Comment: If you feel that above discussion  answers your question, then please accept it.so that our discussion will be helpful for other people coming across it.

Answer (score 1):

JMX provides information from a single node. To have information about entire cluster we collect data from all nodes into Zabbix. Zabbix allows to create graphs and screens that show jmx values from all nodes in one place. E.g. we can see all Read Pending Tasks for all nodes in single graph.

I think, to have separate information for each node in one place it's better solution to diagnose possible issues than to have common aggregate information.

Regarding metrics, I can recommend [Guide to Cassandra Thread Pools](http://www.planetcassandra.org/blog/guide-to-cassandra-thread-pools/) that provides a description of the different cassandra metrics and how to monitor them.